# How do I programmatically launch the "Google Play Games Profile" Game Page

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, google-play-services, google-play-games

I want to **directly launch the Google Play Game Page for my game programmatically** when the player hits this button from the game screen:

[image: Google Play Game Controller Icon]

An example of the page I want to launch to is:
[image: Google Play Game Page]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Xfkv7Sp0JzdzJiWWpFWG8zNHoydnMzWkwzZVJWZDJuUXZr/view?usp=sharing

**Any thoughts/suggestions on doing this?**

PS. I've just taken a random awesome game "BADLAND" as an example :). Hope that's okay!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been a while so I don't know if you found the answer already but I have been working on essentially the same thing today and figured I would share my solution. I found no sources on this online and ended up decompiling the app to look at what it expects for the intents to launch it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
//Clear the activity so the back button returns to your app
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//Manually specify the package and activity name
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.play.games", "com.google.android.gms.games.ui.destination.api.ApiActivity"));
//Not really needed as default happens if you don't specify it.
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
//You must specify the current players user. It ensures that Google Play Games is logged in as the same person.
intent.putExtra("com.google.android.gms.games.ACCOUNT_KEY", Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(googleApiClient));
intent.putExtra("com.google.android.gms.games.SCREEN", 1050); //"Magic" number from the source code for the about page
intent.putExtra("com.google.android.gms.games.GAME", Games.GamesMetadata.getCurrentGame(googleApiClient));
startActivity(intent);
```

Note that the page itself uses a hard coded number. I tested over several versions of Google Play Games and they worked but I still haven't found where the value is defined. You may also want to add in some error handling for cases such as Google Play Games not being installed.

[Details on more pages such as profile compare](http://www.jamesmorrisstudios.us/blogs/post/8-10-12-Google-Play-Games-Deep-Linking-Intents)

[Github Gist of all pages](https://gist.github.com/morris-james/fb3f009538b44931911b)

Comment: Great! Looks like exactly what I was looking for. I'm marking it as the answer. In case I run into issues while I implement this in my app, I'll come back and update here. Thanks a lot for sharing this.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to figure this out. Realy helps. The documentation still lacks this bit and it's really frustrating

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is deprecated now. Do the following:

```
Create these methods in AccountUtil.class (Or whatever you may call it):

fun getGamesAccount(): GoogleSignInAccount? {
    return GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(app)
}

fun getGamesPlayerInfo(): Task<Player>? {
    val account = getGamesAccount()
    return if (account != null) {
        Games.getPlayersClient(app, account).currentPlayer
    } else null
}

fun getPlayerProfileIntent(player: Player): Task<Intent>? {
    val account = getGamesAccount()
    return if (account != null) {
        Games.getPlayersClient(app, account).getCompareProfileIntent(player)
    }else null
}
```

Then you can get the profile intent like this:

```
accountUtil.getGamesPlayerInfo()?.addOnSuccessListener { player ->
            accountUtil.getPlayerProfileIntent(player)?.addOnSuccessListener {
                startActivityForResult(it, PROFILE_REQUEST_CODE)
            }
}

companion object {
    const val PROFILE_REQUEST_CODE = 23423
}
```